# Flutter transform translate appbar leading Button to top on scrolling

Tags: flutter, animation, transform, appbar

I want translate leading Button in app bar when scrolling like below.
button will translate according with scrolled amount.

[image]

and this is what i tried and got. Same thing happened but its not changing with scrolled amount which is not smooth as well

[image]

How can i achieve this kind of smooth transtion based on scrolled amount??

This is my current code

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  
  final scrollcontroller = ScrollController();
  late AnimationController animationController;

@override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
   scrollcontroller.addListener(onScroll);

   animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));

animationController.addListener(() {
  setState(() {});
  });
}

onScroll() {

  if (scrollcontroller.offset < 15) {
      animationController.reverse();
      print(animationController.value);

  } else if (scrollcontroller.offset > 15) {
      animationController.forward();
      print(animationController.value);
    }
}

@override
Widget build(context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      leading: Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(0, -animationController.value * 35),
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
      title: Text("test"),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF51d3e3),
    body: NotificationListener<UserScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        if (notification.direction == ScrollDirection.forward) {
          // print("Scrolling up");
        } else if (notification.direction == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
          // print("Scrolling down");
          // print(scrollcontroller.offset);
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 20),
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: scrollcontroller,
          itemCount: 9,
          itemBuilder: (content, index) {
            return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
              child: PlaceholderCardTall(
                  height: 200,
                  color: const Color(0xFF99D3F7),
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFC7EAFF)),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Middle top part contains title?

Comment: yes it is. I just need the leading only

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SliverPersistentHeader`, play with `shrinkOffset`.

```dart
class CSLVW extends StatelessWidget {
  const CSLVW({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            pinned: true,
            delegate: CustomAppBar(),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(height: 1133),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class CustomAppBar extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    var factionDatabaseSnapshot;

    return Container(
      color: Colors.purple,
      height: maxExtent,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: 20,
            top: -shrinkOffset + 10,
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: null,
              icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => kToolbarHeight * 1.5;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) =>
      false;
}
```